# Modular invariance of CFT

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, definition, invariants

I am looking at the Cardy formula for entropy in CFT, and in the article ['Kerr/CFT correspondence and its Extensions'](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/Articles/lrr-2012-11/fulltext.html) there is a sentence:

> In any unitary and modular invariant CFT, the asymptotic growth of states...

I've looked a bit, but couldn't find any simple explanation of the term modular invariant CFT.

All I find is that [modular invariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_invariance) is the invariance under the group $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. But what does that mean, what's the physical explanation of it and what's it's effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ref : Polchinski Vol $1$, pages $146-150$

With a torus topology, with identifications $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2) \sim (\sigma_1, \sigma_2) + 2\pi(m,n)$, one may bring the worldsheet metrics to the form $ds^2 = |d\sigma_1 + \tau d\sigma_2|^2 = dw d \bar w$, where $\tau$ is  a complex constant (the moduli). The periodicity is expressed  by $w \sim w + 2\pi(m+n\tau)$, with $m,n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

There are additional redundancies. The value $\tau+1$ generates the same kind of indendification for $w$, with $(m,n) \to (m-n,n)$. The value $\frac{1}{\tau}$ also generates the same kind of indendification for $w$, with $w \to \tau w$ and $(m,n) \to (n,m)$. $\tau \to \tau+1$ and $\tau \to \frac{1}{\tau}$ are the two generators of the $SL(2,Z)$ group (some people call it the [modular group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group), while others give this name to $PSL(2,Z)$) , the group of transformations $z \to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, with $a,b,c,d$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $ad-bc=1$. This represents the diffeomorphism of the torus.

This allows to take a [fundamental region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane),  for the upper half-plane modulo $PSL(2,Z)$. The fact that we may choose a fundamental region without the origin $z=0$, gives the idea, that string theory may be well-suited to avoid some infinite quantities.

Comment: How could I phrase that in layman terms? XD Is it possible to explaine this to someone who's not directly involved in physics? Or not in this area?

Comment: Hard ! Well, let's say that $PSL(2,Z)$ is a symmetry of the theory .In my string theory example, it is due to the torus topology. Now, at some point, you need to enter in the details. Morevoer, the origin of the $PSL(2,Z)$ symmetry may depends on the particular conformal theory you are looking at.

Comment: I'll accept this even tho I'm not really sure how to explain this in layman terms :\